# Golang: Multiple structs marshall issue: json format

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling

For the following code, I get the error:

```
type A struct{
    B_j []B `json:"A"` 
}
type B struct
{
    X string
    Y string

}

func main() {
    xmlFile, _ := os.Open("test.xml")

    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var t root
    err2 := xml.Unmarshal(b, &rpc)
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err2)
        return
    }

    for _, name := range t.name{
        t := A{B_j : []B{X : name.text, Y: name.type }} // line:#25

        s, _ := json.MarshalIndent(t,"", " ")

    os.Stdout.Write(s)
        }
}
```

---

```
# command-line-arguments
./int2.go:25: undefined: X
./int2.go:25: cannot use name.Text (type string) as type B in array or slice literal
./int2.go:25: undefined: Y
./int2.go:25: cannot use name.type (type string) as type B in array or slice literal
```

In my output, I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
{A: {{X:1 ,Y: 2}, {X:2 ,Y: 2}, {X: 2,Y: 2}}}
```

Struct calling another struct to get the pattern above.

Comment: Yesterday you posted question about XML unmarshall issue of your RPC XML. I have analyzed and answered your question. You didn't accepted the answer, simply you replied "Thanks, that's stupid of me" and deleted the SO question. I suggest not to do that going forward, it is not good for the community.

Comment: @jeevatkm : that was definitely an unconscious error from my end. Its back now. Apologies!

Comment: Thanks, no issues. I just thought to bring it your attention. BTW I hope that answer solved your issue. Please accept the answer in SO.

Comment: Is the quoted file `int2.go`? Which line is 156? The compiler error is telling you what's wrong, but without any context there's no way for anyone else to help you.

Comment: @Adrian updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have problem at this line-

```
t := A{B_j: []B{X: name.text, Y: name.type }}
```

You're not creating a slice properly. Try following-

```
t := A{B_j: []B{{X: name.text, Y: name.type}}}
```

---

Let's do it better way-

```
var bj []B
for _, name := range t.name{
  bj = append(bj, B{X: name.text,Y: name.type})
}

t := A{B_j: bj}
s, _ := json.MarshalIndent(t,"", " ")      
os.Stdout.Write(s)
```

Sample program with static values https://play.golang.org/p/a2ZDV8lgWP

Note: `type` is language keyword, do not use it as variable name.

Comment: That fixed the error, but the output is like this:

{A : [ {X: 1, Y:2 } ] } , {A : [ {X: 1, Y:2 } ] }, {A : [ {X: 1, Y:2 } ] }

I am trying to produce something like:

{A: {{X:1 ,Y: 2}, {X:2 ,Y: 2}, {X: 2,Y: 2}}}

Comment: should it be var bj []B ?

Comment: You're welcome, added golang play link for reference.